# Collection of numbers to a single output, single output to the collection.

Tags: number-theory

Is there a function or is it possible to make a function that will take in a collection of numbers (say 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7) and gives an output(say 56 for example) and another function that takes 56 and converts them back (to 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7) without disrupting the order. ?

Comment: Can you give an example with more context? What you are asking for is too general to be meaningless. Yes, of course you have output a single number and output again the original list. But what do you specifically have in mind? It depends what you want $f$ to do.

Comment: Do you know ahead of how many numbers there are in the collection.  Are this numbers integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers in your collection are all **non-negative integers** and **bounded** by a power of $10$ (say, by $10^b$), then a possible function would be:

$$\begin{align}
f(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1},x_n) &= x_1 \left[ \left( 10^b \right)^{n-1} \right] + x_2 \left[ \left( 10^b \right)^{n-2} \right] + \ldots + x_{n-1} \left( 10^b \right) + x_{n} \\
\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \left[ \left( 10^b \right)^{n-i} \right] \\
\end{align}$$

The "return" function would be $g(N)=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1},x_n\}$, where

$$x_i = \left\lfloor \frac{N}{\left(10^b\right)^{n-i}} \right\rfloor - 10^b \left\lfloor \frac{N}{\left(10^b\right)^{n-(i-1)}} \right\rfloor$$

As an example, suppose your collection of numbers is $\{37,82,4,51\}$ (bounded by $10^2$) then

$$\begin{align}
f(37,82,4,51) &= 37 \left[ \left(10^2\right)^{4-1} \right] + 82 \left[ \left(10^2\right)^{4-2} \right] + 4 \left[ \left(10^2\right)^{4-3} \right] + 51 \left[ \left(10^2\right)^{4-4} \right] \\
\\
&= 37 \left(10^6\right) + 82 \left(10^4\right) + 4 \left(10^2\right) + 51 \left(10^0\right) \\
\\
&= 37820451
\end{align}$$

Then to return to the original collection, $g(x)$ would calculate, as one example,

$$\begin{align}
x_2 &= \left\lfloor \frac{37820451}{\left(10^2\right)^{4-2}} \right\rfloor - 10^2 \left\lfloor \frac{37820451}{\left(10^2\right)^{4-(2-1)}} \right\rfloor \\
\\
&= \left\lfloor \frac{37820451}{10^4} \right\rfloor - 10^2 \left\lfloor \frac{37820451}{10^6} \right\rfloor \\
\\
&= \lfloor 3782.0451 \rfloor - 100 \lfloor 37.820451 \rfloor \\
\\
&= 3782 - 3700 \\
\\
&= 82
\end{align}$$